# Replacement for windows Indexing Service

Tags: indexing-service

I run a website that has a search feature. The search catalog is being generated by Windows Server 2008's Indexing Service. I then query the catalog and return search results using classic ASP.

I have run into problems where pages in my site are not indexed and returned as results for a search. Also, documents such as PDF files are not returned.

I am looking to replace the indexing service and need help finding a program to create a catalog I can search. I have checked with Google and am not finding programs that create a search catalog. I did however get a long list of 3rd party websites that would create a search engine for me site if I wanted to pay. :-(

What do people recommend for hosting a search engine as part of a website?

Mike